# Node js dynamically require pages issue

Tags: node.js

I created a node js app,which contains the following code in app.js

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
var language = (req.headers['accept-language'] == 'ar' ? ar : en);
lang = require('./server/lang/' + language);
next();
});
```

Inside lang folder ar.js and en.js are there.The responses are send based on this language.The lang variable is set globally and i can use it any where in the app.When trying to send request using postman it is working perfectly and lang variable is set based on accep-language header .But  when large number of requests are send from client side its not working correctly ie the lang variable is not correctly set.Is any solution available for this.

Comment: What are `ar` and `en`? Have u declared them? If not, enclose them in quotes like, `'ar'` and `'en'`.

Answer (score 0):

Packaging happens just before the runtime, so language variable don't have value yet.

You can do something like this instead:

```
var ar = require("./server/lang/ar");
var en = require("./server/lang/en");
var language = (req.headers['accept-language'] == 'ar' ? ar : en);
```

Please, let me know if that works for you.

Or when you have more languages, you could use a huge switch-case statement, or require all languages in an object.